# which radeon driver do I get?

Tags: ati

I have updated my Ubuntu kernel to 3.12 so I can take advantage of updated DPM.

I am trying to find firmware for my radeon from this website

http://people.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/radeon_ucode/

I did a `lspci | grep VGA`

and I get this

```
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS880M [Mobility Radeon HD 4225/4250]
```

Which firmware do I use so that I can add it to `/lib/radeon`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4225/4250 is a RV610/630 chipset, so you will only need `R600_rlc.bin`. However, from what I can tell (based on the file modification times), Ubuntu 13.10 already includes the latest firmware for R610/R630.

I think you may only need to enable DPM from the kernel command line, since DPM is not enabled by default. Just boot with `radeon.dpm=1`.

If DPM is enabled, you should see something similar to the following in System Log:

```
Nov 13 01:19:39 yjwong-laptop kernel: [    7.046550] switching from power state:
Nov 13 01:19:39 yjwong-laptop kernel: [    7.046552]    ui class: none
Nov 13 01:19:39 yjwong-laptop kernel: [    7.046553]    internal class: boot 
Nov 13 01:19:39 yjwong-laptop kernel: [    7.046555]    caps: video 
Nov 13 01:19:39 yjwong-laptop kernel: [    7.046557]    uvd    vclk: 0 dclk: 0
Nov 13 01:19:39 yjwong-laptop kernel: [    7.046558]        power level 0    sclk: 55000 mclk: 66700 vddc: 1100
Nov 13 01:19:39 yjwong-laptop kernel: [    7.046560]        power level 1    sclk: 55000 mclk: 66700 vddc: 1100
Nov 13 01:19:39 yjwong-laptop kernel: [    7.046561]        power level 2    sclk: 55000 mclk: 66700 vddc: 1100
Nov 13 01:19:39 yjwong-laptop kernel: [    7.046562]    status: c b 
Nov 13 01:19:39 yjwong-laptop kernel: [    7.046564] switching to power state:
Nov 13 01:19:39 yjwong-laptop kernel: [    7.046565]    ui class: performance
Nov 13 01:19:39 yjwong-laptop kernel: [    7.046566]    internal class: none
Nov 13 01:19:39 yjwong-laptop kernel: [    7.046568]    caps: single_disp video 
Nov 13 01:19:39 yjwong-laptop kernel: [    7.046571]    uvd    vclk: 0 dclk: 0
Nov 13 01:19:39 yjwong-laptop kernel: [    7.046572]        power level 0    sclk: 22000 mclk: 30000 vddc: 950
Nov 13 01:19:39 yjwong-laptop kernel: [    7.046573]        power level 1    sclk: 30000 mclk: 50000 vddc: 950
Nov 13 01:19:39 yjwong-laptop kernel: [    7.046575]        power level 2    sclk: 55000 mclk: 66700 vddc: 1100
Nov 13 01:19:39 yjwong-laptop kernel: [    7.046576]    status: r 
Nov 13 01:19:39 yjwong-laptop kernel: [    7.050341] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
```

Comment: OK thank you and where can I see system log?

Comment: You can see the System Log using the "System Log" application (`gnome-system-log`) or by typing `dmesg`. To scroll through the output, you can use the `dmesg | less` command.

Comment: Thanks and it seems DPM is enabled and the driver file is already there but there is no acceleration? Do you have any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by no acceleration? OpenGL applications not working / running slowly? Or are you referring to video decode? DPM only helps in power saving; whether or not acceleration is enabled is independent of DPM...

Comment: Hm I thought DPM would help the graphic acceleration. Oh well thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Well, it would help in speed for those GPUs whose "boot" power profile is lower than the "performance" profile. The kernel log tells you if such a switch has occurred (as it can be seen from my log above).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not touch `/lib`. Second, you might want to check `modinfo radeon` to check what driver/module are you using. If you installed the 3.12 kernel you are most likely using already the latest driver.

Comment: OK thanks will check soon. I have installed kernel 3.12 but it seems acceleration is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that 3d hardware acceleration is no longer available with this chipset, I have the same unit and been trying to get 3D back up after an update switched me to software accel.

Its a total pain in the arse as I really like Unity and now its nearly unusable on my Acer 7450 which is my main work laptop....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the same chipset. The reason is that you are probably falling back to llvmpipe rendering. I resolved it by installing the xserver-xorg-video-ati package. See also [How to enable Unity 3D support in 12.04 using open-source drivers for RadeonHD cards?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122339/how-to-enable-unity-3d-support-in-12-04-using-open-source-drivers-for-radeonhd-c) for more details.